# Xcode 4.3.2 UINavigationBar image background

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xcode4.3

I am creating a tabBar application in xCode 4.3.2 with UINavigation controller. I am using following code in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
   self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1] autorelease], viewController2, nil];
   self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
```

Now problem is that i want custom background image in navigation bar. The solutions i have found are writing subclass of UINavigationBar and set new subclass in interface builder. But in my case i am setting navigation controller programmatically then how to achieve this?
I have also tried creating category as

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

But its not working at all.

Comment: You want to set Background image of Tabbar or Navigation Bar. Your question heading is releated to navigation bar and you posted code for tabbar???

Comment: Mitesh Khatri, i want to set background image of navigationBar, i posted code to show how i am adding navigation controller. I tried to subclass navigationBar, but i don't know how to set navigatioBar class to my new subclass as i am doing all programmatically. Thanx waiting for your reply

Comment: You can see my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386633/cant-set-a-background-image-to-uinavigationcontroller/17105203#17105203

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Navigationbar use this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavBarImage.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

and for Tabbar:

    // not supported on iOS4    
    UITabBar *tabBar = [tabController tabBar];
    if ([tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)])
    {
        // set it just for this instance
        [tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_brn.jpg"]];

        // set for all
        // [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ios 4 code here
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanx Mitesh Khatri, but i am looking for backword compatible solution, atleast for iOS 4.